Why is the location of core.longpath restricted to 260 characters with libgit2?
According to libgit2's documentation longpaths will work for a repository, but only in the working directory.  The root of the repository (the .git folder) needs to be in a path less than 260 characters.
I might be missing something.  If long paths are enabled on a computer, windows API can access paths longer than 260 characters.  Makes me think libgit2 could also find a local config file that has a path longer than 260 characters.
What is the limitation that requires a local config file to be in a path less than 260 characters?

It is explained well: This definition is required to avoid a paradoxical setting: if you had a repository in a folder that was 280 characters long, how would you know whether core.longpaths support should be enabled? Even if core.longpaths was set to true in a system configuration file, the repository itself may set core.longpaths to false in its configuration file, which you could only read if core.longpaths were set to true.

@HansPassant  The documentation is making some logical conclusions that I don't understand, or, it is using knowledge that I don't have. I believe what I'm missing is what a local core.longpaths signifies.  If set to false, what does that mean?  Git won't use long paths for that specific repo, or something else?

Yes, that's what it means.  The less glamorous way to interpret "paradoxical": when a bug has been around too long without getting fixed then it becomes a feature.

Yes, if (and only if) core.longpaths = true is set, then git clients, including libgit2, will refuse to open paths longer than 260 characters. core.longpaths defaults to false.
Imagine that you have some path like C:\<LONG_PATH>\my_project where the length of that path is more than 260 characters. Now imagine that you cd into that directory and run libgit2 status. What should happen?
Well, libgit2 should look at the local repository git configuration in C:\<LONG_PATH>\my_project\.git\config for core.longpaths. Except that if it wanted to read that file, core.longpaths = true must be set. Except that we can't know the value of core.longpaths unless we open that file. Which we can't, because if we wanted to read that file, core.longpaths = true must be set. ad infinitum.
